# Best Java framework to manage/create dynamic security policy rules?

Tags: java, web-applications, security

Typically in any web application, the major security concern is securing the resources from the malicious users who are trying to access un-authorized resources. They can change a value in the request parameter and try to access something that doesn't belong to that particular user.

For Example:
`http://blah.com/id=foo`
a user can change this to `http://blah.com/id=bar` and try to access the `bar` resource to access it.

With restful services this may lead to greater security concerns as the restful URL's are rather self explanatory.

eg:

`http://hotels.com/hotels/1`
a user can easily guess and change the id to 2 to see the details of it..

One design is to check at every request manually to see the access rights for the resources and deny it if needed. 
but this is a cumbersome and not maintainable.

So the question is "Is there any tool/framework that can help achieve this in a easy manner? I know spring security supports static rules not dynamic.

Comment: Hi Teja,
i am exactly looking for same answers. Is there any way we can develop a web application where we can inject different security policies. For example in SE-Linux which is using Flask architecture where a security server is running comprising all security policies in centralized manner. I am researching on developing a java based web application where a security server is running and we should be able to compile a security policy and generate a binary from security policy and injecting that security policy into security server and then the java based web application runs that policy.

Answer (score 1):

Over the last couple of years, the de-factory standard for this has become [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/index.html). This sits in frotn of any old java webapp (not just Spring webapps) and provides an interception authentication and authorization layer of your choice.

It's very powerful, although also rather complicated (over-complicated, IMO).

Comment: Spring Security is great, but its documentation sucks. I couldn't still find any really awesome manual.

Comment: Over complicated is true indeed but do you know of any easier alternative that plays well with Spring besides rolling your own?

Comment: I am currently using spring security but when coming to the security rules/url protection it doesn't had much capabilities, the decision making and voting api sucks

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend looking into [Seam Security](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.1.1.GA/reference/en-US/html/security.html). It can even be tied into a rules system.

**edit:** I believe you would need the Seam Core package for this to work. However, I have never tried using it without Seam, so I can't be positive about its dependencies.

Comment: looks good, but is that modular enough to plug it into any applications, even if it is not done using seam?